# Python 3.1 and Sublime Text 2 error

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext

I want to use a SublimeText2 as IDE for developing applications in Python.

I have the following problem :

When I make a new file, save it as a python and do Tools -> Build System -> Python
CTRL + B

I get this error:

```
Please type your name and press enter: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/strielok/Desktop/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    personsname = raw_input("Please type your name and press enter: ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
[Finished]
```

Here is the code of the program:

```
 personsname = raw_input("Please type your name and press enter: ")
    print "Hello " +personsname
```

However when I run this code from terminal (I am on Mac), it works perfectly.

Any idea what the problem might be ?

Comment: is the indentation in the second line in your code?

Comment: I can only guess, but that guess is that Sublime closes, or doesn't create, standard input for the application. Better ask at the forums.

Comment: Apart from the issue with stdin, it appears that you're not actually running it in Python 3.1, because `raw_input` is just `input` on Python 3.

Comment: As @ThomasK indicates no one of the two lines (raw_input and print as a statement) would work in py3k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install sublimeREPL and then choose `Tools->sublimerepl->python`.

Reference：http://gimo.me/sublime-text2-skills/

Comment: Link is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from Sublime Text's forums, seems that stdin will not be connected with anything so it's expected.

Source: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1519&p=6908&hilit=python+input#wrap

Answer (score 0):

I've written [a plugin](https://github.com/eric-wieser/build-with-input) which allows builds in sublime text to take input. It's a bit rough around the edges, but it works on my machine.