# Python 3: EOF when reading a line (Sublime Text 2 is angry)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext2, eof

```
while True:
    reply = input('Enter text')
    if reply == 'stop': break
    print(reply.upper())
```

The result was:

> ```
> Enter text:Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\PythonProjects\5.py", line 2, in <module>
>     reply = input('Enter text:')
> EOFError: EOF when reading a line
> [Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
> ```

It is only in Sublime Text 2. I tried IDLE, tried command line, everything is perfect.
Why should Subleme shout at me?

By the way, maybe you could also explain my what EOF may mean in such situation. Of course, I have read in the documentation, that if EOF is read from input, the appropriate error is raised. I would like to model this situation. Is input only about the keyboard? If yes, what combination of keys should I input to get EOF?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure about the rest of your question, but EOF is usually `ctrl` + `D`

Answer (score 36):

I had the same problem. The problem with the Sublime Text's default console is that it does not support input.

To solve it, you have to install a package called SublimeREPL. SublimeREPL provides a Python interpreter which accepts input.

There is an [article](http://www.bestpythonide.com/python-input-eoferror-in-sublime-text-2.html) that explains the solution in detail.

[GitHub page for SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL)

Comment: The link to the article is no longer working, I think you should check it

Answer (score 11):

`help(input)` shows what keyboard shortcuts produce EOF, namely, Unix: <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>, Windows: <kbd>Ctrl-Z+Return</kbd>:

> input([prompt]) -> string
>
> Read a string from standard input.  The trailing newline is stripped.
>   If the user hits EOF (Unix: Ctl-D, Windows: Ctl-Z+Return), raise
>   EOFError. On Unix, GNU readline is used if enabled.  The prompt
>   string, if given, is printed without a trailing newline before
>   reading.

You could reproduce it using an empty file:

```
$ touch empty
$ python3 -c "input()" < empty
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

You could use `/dev/null` or `nul` (Windows) as an empty file for reading. `os.devnull` shows the name that is used by your OS:

```
$ python3 -c "import os; print(os.devnull)"
/dev/null
```

Note: `input()` happily accepts input from a file/pipe. You don't need `stdin` to be connected to the terminal:

```
$ echo abc | python3 -c "print(input()[::-1])"
cba
```

Either handle `EOFError` in your code:

```
try:
    reply = input('Enter text')
except EOFError:
    break
```

Or configure your editor to provide a non-empty input when it runs your script e.g., by using a customized command line if it allows it: `python3 "%f" < input_file`

Answer (score 10):

EOF is a special out-of-band signal which means the end of input. It's not a character (though in the old DOS days, 0x1B acted like EOF), but rather a signal from the OS that the input has ended.

On Windows, you can "input" an EOF by pressing `Ctrl+Z` at the command prompt. This signals the terminal to close the input stream, which presents an EOF to the running program. Note that on other OSes or terminal emulators, EOF is usually signalled using `Ctrl+D`.

As for your issue with Sublime Text 2, it seems that `stdin` is not connected to the terminal when running a program within Sublime, and so consequently programs start off connected to an empty file (probably `nul` or `/dev/null`). See also [Python 3.1 and Sublime Text 2 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142290/python-3-1-and-sublime-text-2-error).

Comment: Is there a way to connect stdin properly so you can input into the terminal?

Comment: I don't personally use Sublime, but it seems the leading suggestion is to install [SublimeREPL](http://sublimerepl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 5):

It seems as of now, the only solution is still to install SublimeREPL.

To extend on Raghav's answer, it can be quite annoying to have to go into the Tools->SublimeREPL->Python->Run command every time you want to run a script with input, so I devised a quick key binding that may be handy:

To enable it, go to Preferences->Key Bindings - User, and copy this in there:

```
[
    {"keys":["ctrl+r"] , 
    "caption": "SublimeREPL: Python - RUN current file",
    "command": "run_existing_window_command", 
    "args":
        {
            "id": "repl_python_run",
            "file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu"
        }
    },
]
```

Naturally, you would just have to change the "keys" argument to change the shortcut to whatever you'd like.

Answer (score -2):

```
try:
    value = raw_input()
    do_stuff(value) # next line was found 
except (EOFError):
   break #end of file reached
```

This seems to be proper usage of raw_input when dealing with the end of the stream of input from piped input.
[Refer this post][1]