# EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to define a function to make the perimeter of a rectangle. Here is the code:

```
width = input()
height = input()
def rectanglePerimeter(width, height):
   return ((width + height)*2)
print(rectanglePerimeter(width, height))
```

I think I haven't left any arguments opened or anything like that.

Comment: And what do you enter when `input()` asks you for input? Are you running this in a terminal or in an IDE? Note that `input()` returns a string, not an `int` so your calculation will fail.

Comment: related: [Python 3: EOF when reading a line (Sublime Text 2 is angry)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12547683/4279)

Comment: What's your question? To start, do you understand what that error message means? Next, how are you running your code? IDE, terminal, online testing site... Please [edit] to clarify. See [ask].

Comment: To be clear, if you run your code in a system that doesn't provide any input on stdin, or not enough lines, you'll get that error. For a minimal example in Bash: `printf '' | python3 -c 'input()'`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
width, height = map(int, input().split())
def rectanglePerimeter(width, height):
   return ((width + height)*2)
print(rectanglePerimeter(width, height))
```

Running it like this produces:

```
% echo "1 2" | test.py
6
```

---

I suspect IDLE is simply passing a single string to your script. The first `input()` is slurping the entire string. Notice what happens if you put some print statements in after the calls to `input()`:

```
width = input()
print(width)
height = input()
print(height)
```

Running `echo "1 2" | test.py` produces

```
1 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/unutbu/pybin/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    height = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Notice the first print statement prints the entire string `'1 2'`. The second call to `input()` raises the `EOFError` (end-of-file error).

So a simple pipe such as the one I used only allows you to pass one string. Thus you can only call `input()` once. You must then process this string, split it on whitespace, and convert the string fragments to ints yourself. That is what

```
width, height = map(int, input().split())
```

does.

Note, there are other ways to pass input to your program. If you had run `test.py` in a terminal, then you could have typed `1` and `2` separately with no problem. Or, you could have written a program with [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) to simulate a terminal, passing `1` and `2` programmatically. Or, you could use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) to pass arguments on the command line, allowing you to call your program with

```
test.py 1 2
```

Comment: Ok, but what is that doing differently and why would mine fail?

Comment: How were you running your program? Was it the same way, `echo "1 2" | test.py`?

Comment: No, I was just running it from IDLE

Answer (score 10):

Use a `try` / `except` block to get rid of the EOF error.

```py
try:
    width = input()
    height = input()
    def rectanglePerimeter(width, height):
       return ((width + height)*2)
    print(rectanglePerimeter(width, height))
except EOFError as e:
    print(end="")
```

Comment: This makes it so the script doesn't do anything if it hits that error. How is that helpful? And why on Earth would you put the `def` in the `try` block? It should be above it if anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

convert your inputs to ints:

```
width = int(input())
height = int(input())
```

Comment: Depends on whether this is Python 2 or 3. Remember that `print()` can work in python 2 (although it probably is 3)

Comment: yes, but the question is tagged with `python-3.x, so i'm assuming py3 ;)

Comment: Ok I tried the int() thing but it still came up with that same error. I am entering numbers in and using IDLE 3.

Comment: @astrognocci WOW, I did not see that. Epic fail by me :p

Comment: Are you running the program directly from idle (pressing F5) ? Apparently some terminals can't handle input correctly. I don't remember IDLE having trouble with it, but i haven't used it in a while and don't have it here, so maybe that's it