# Raw_input() Python (Learn Python the Hard Way Exercise 11)

Tags: python, input, raw-input

I am doing the Asking Questions exercise from "Learn Python the Hard Way" 3rd edition by Zed Shaw where my code looks like:

```
print "How old are you?",

age = raw_input()

print "How tall are you?",

height = raw_input()

print "How much do you weigh?",

weight = raw_input()

print "So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy." % (age, height, weight)
```

and output should look like:

```
How old are you? 38

How tall are you? 6'2"

How much do you weigh? 180lbs

So, you're '38' old, '6\'2"' tall and '180lbs' heavy.
```

However, because I am using Python 3, output initially looks like:

```
How old are you?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 2, in <module>
    age = raw_input()
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
```

and then like once I replace raw_input() with input():

```
How old are you?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 2, in <module>
    age = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: Looks like Python 2 code on a Python 3 system. On the other hand `print "How old are you?",` seems to work and that's Python 2 syntax. There's something fishy here.

Comment: print should be print(). that's another difference between Py2 and Py3

Comment: Maybe related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/17675925/10077

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code you have is python 2 code. Here is a revised version with python 3 syntax.

[Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3) is some reading about the `.format()` call in the last line. I think the .format method is a lot easier to understand.

And [here](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_input.php) is some reading for the `input()` function in python 3

```
age = input("How old are you?")

height = input("How tall are you?")

weight = input("How much do you weigh?")

print("So, you're {} old, {} tall and {} heavy.".format(age, height, weight))
```

Comment: I do a:

print("How old are you?",)

age = input("How old are you?")

and get:

How old are you?

How old are you?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 2, in <module>
    age = input("How old are you?")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: Can you confirm what version of python you are using? Also you don't have to `print("How old are you?")` before the input. The input will automatically print "How old are you?" to the terminal before getting the users input.

Comment: Hello, it doesn't matter which version of python he's using, the code you did will work for both python2.xx and python3.xx

Comment: Not quite true. If you use a `print "something"` in python3 it will give you a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. You have to use `print('something')`. That is why I am confused. He stated he was using python3 but is using python 2 print syntax.

Answer (score -1):

For Python 3 try replacing all of your "raw_input()" with simply "input()" which has replaced "raw_input()"