# Removing EOF error from int(input()) python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a pattern in HackerRank and as far as I can tell, my solution works.

```
size = int(input())
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
for i in range(size):
    textp = "-".join(letters[size - 1: size - (1 + i): -1])
    textn = "-".join(letters[size - i: size: 1])
    print(textp.rjust(size + 2, '-') + '-' + letters[size - (1 + i)] + '-' + textn.ljust(size + 2, '-'))
for i in range(size - 2, -1, -1):
    textp = "-".join(letters[size - 1: size - (1 + i): -1])
    textn = "-".join(letters[size - i: size: 1])
    print(textp.rjust(size + 2, '-') + '-' + letters[size - (1 + i)] + '-' + textn.ljust(size + 2, '-'))
```

prints out:

```
--------e--------
------e-d-e------
----e-d-c-d-e----
--e-d-c-b-c-d-e--
e-d-c-b-a-b-c-d-e
--e-d-c-b-c-d-e--
----e-d-c-d-e----
------e-d-e------
--------e--------
```

But when I try to submit it I get

```
File "solution.py", line 12, in <module>
n = int(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I'm new to python so I'm not sure how to resolve this error. The code works fine and I don't understand why the input() function is messing up.

Comment: What do you submit exactly?

Comment: this error is saying you're trying to read for an input this assignment doesn't provide. I.e., you have too many `input()`s in the code. Also, this line is not even in the question code: `n = int(input())`

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675925/eoferror-eof-when-reading-a-line

Comment: @Simon as input I type in a number that decides how wide the diamond pattern will be. Its a single integer on a single line. So for the example above I typed in 5, therefore the pattern was 5 letters wide.

Comment: @Marat yea I realize that I never even typed that line which is why I'm even more confused. And I only have one input line which is where I type the single number that decides the size of the pattern, so I'm not sure why too many inputs would be the problem

Answer (score 1):

OK so i figured it out. There was a little tab at the bottom of the interpreter that had this code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   n = int(input())
   print_rangoli(n)
```

I had to remove the `size = int(input())` and I had to enclose the code in a function called `print_ragnoli(s)`