# I am making a chat robot but it gives an eof error

Tags: python, user-input, chatbot, eof

I was making a chat robot in python but when I executed the code I got an eof error
here is the code:

```
ai_talked= "0"
textreadyyet="no"
playermessage = input("Talk here:")

def playertalk():
 while textreadyyet=="no":
  if textreadyyet== "Yes":
   print(playermessage)
  else:
   textreadyyet= "Yes"
   print(playermessage)
  
  
  playertalk()
  print(playermessage)
  
  def aialk():
    if ai_talked=="0":
        print("Hello!")

  aialk()
```

it gives an eof error in the 3rd line

Comment: did you press an enter after the prompt shown?

Comment: also did You enter any text?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675925/eoferror-eof-when-reading-a-line. Also `textreadyyet` needs to either passed to `playertalk()` as an argument or as `global textreadyyet` within the function, or else that will become an error as well.