# EOFError: EOF when reading a line. How to solve if i have input and it works on IDE but not on codeforces.com

Tags: python, python-3.x

Task:
You are given a rectangular board of size M × N cells. An unlimited number of standard dominoes of 2 × 1 squares are also given. Dominos can be rotated. It is required to put as many dominoes as possible on the board so that the following conditions are met:

1. Each domino completely covers two squares of the board.
2. No two dominoes overlap.
3. Each domino is completely inside the board. Touching the edges of the permissions.

Find the maximum number of dominoes that can be stacked with the given restrictions.

***My CODE***:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
print(a*b // 2)
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.pys3", line 1, in <module>
    a = int(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EOFError: EOF when reading a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675925/eoferror-eof-when-reading-a-line)

Comment: Check the codeforces instructions again how the input is supposed to be passed into your code/function. I suspect it's not with `input()`.