# python input() doesn't work in IDE - eof

Tags: python, input, ide, eof

I've a problem with input(), raw_input() commands in my NINJA-IDE. When I tried to type in NINJA-IDE command line:

```
f = input('Enter your name:')

f = raw_input('Enter your name:')
```

it gave me such result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

But when I typed this commands in shell command line it works properly.My sys.version in NINJA_IDE is 2.7.3. I can't find any solution. Is it related with IDE preferences or environment variables $PATH or $PYTHONPATH?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, ninja IDE does not let you use input, like [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1756180.html)

Maybe your text editor does not support `input()` like in this [case with sublime text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547683/python-3-eof-when-reading-a-line-sublime-text-2-is-angry). Sometimes this is related to the fact that the editor does not have access to `stdin` where you get the values in the console.

In the case of sublime text you can install SublimeREPL, maybe there's something similar for ninja ide.