# Python: Replace String in a .txt file

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, sys

```
import os, sys
pandaFile = open("panda.txt", "w")
pandaRead = pandaFile.read()

if "NOON" in pandaRead:
    print("Enter a noon:")
    noon = input()
    str.replace("NOON",noon)

if "ADJECTIVE" in pandaRead:
    print("Enter an adjective:")
    adjective = input()
    str.replace("ADJECTIVE", adjective)

if "VERB" in pandaRead:
    print("Enter and verb:")
    verb = input()
    str.replace("VERB",verb)

newcontent = open("panda.txt","w")
```

My goal is to open the file "Panda.txt" file. If there is *ADVERB*, *VERB*, or *NOON*, replace these string by the user input.And re-write the "panda.txt" file.
My error code is:

`pandaRead = pandaFile.read()
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable`

I am using Sublime text 2 with Python 3.4 on a Windows Vista Home Version.

Comment: So what is your actual question ?

Comment: Where in your code do you get errors?

Comment: I suggest you should do some tutorials on file input output and regular expressions

Comment: It doesn't work. I have an error message pandaRead = pandaFile.read()
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable. Thanks

Comment: Replace your line 2 with: `pandaFile = open("panda.txt", "r")` to open your file in read mode and not write

Comment: Thanks Antoine. It works. But now I need to write into the panda.txt file.

Answer (score 2):

There was several errors within your code. I will explain them to you, but for further development, please always keep the [Python reference website](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/) to see the usage of the methods you call.

Here are the various errors I had to deal with from your code:

- Open your file, [specifying you want to read it](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html?highlight=open#io.open)

  `pandaFile = open("panda.txt", "w")`
- Do not print your prompt, [but use the input argument to set a prompt](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input) 

  `print("Enter a noon:")
  noon = input()`
- The replace method should be called on a String instance, not the class, [and it returns the new value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.replace#str.replace)

  `str.replace("NOON",noon)`
- Actually write your new String [inside the opened file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=file.write#file.write)

  `newcontent = open("panda.txt","w")`

Taking these into account, the following code sample is (I assume) what you intend to do:

```
import os , sys

# With is a special bloc statement,
# closing your variable pandaFile at the end of the bloc.
with open("panda.txt", "r") as pandaFile:
    pandaRead = pandaFile.read()

if "NOON" in pandaRead:
    noon = input("Enter a noon:")
    pandaRead = pandaRead.replace("NOON", noon) 

if "ADJECTIVE" in pandaRead:
    adjective = input("Enter an adjective:")
    pandaRead = pandaRead.replace("ADJECTIVE", adjective)

if "VERB" in pandaRead:
    verb = input("Enter and verb:")
    pandaRead = pandaRead.replace("VERB",verb)

with open("panda.txt", "w") as pandaFile:
    pandaFile.write(pandaRead)
```

Comment: Thanks Antoine. Clean code! Now I am getting the error message adjective = input("Enter an adjective:")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line . I was thinkng maybe it's because I am using Sublime text. And it doesn't really allow input().But the first input for the noon works.

Comment: Sorry but I can't reproduce your errors, i am working on linux though. How do you run your script and what do you try to input?

Comment: That's alright. Thanks a lot though. I run the script from the command line.I have more than 1 NOON , maybe that's why?

Comment: I guess this is the command line from sublime text since your problem is quite similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547683/python-3-eof-when-reading-a-line-sublime-text-2-is-angry