# Running python scripts in nautilus

Tags: python, eof, nautilus

I have written a python script, made it executable and pasted it in

```
~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts
```

The problem is that my script needs some user inputs and while it does that, nautilus generates error saying

```
Enter your username: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sumit/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/sms.py", line 30, in <module>
    username = input("Enter your username: ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

However the script works fine when I assign the variables in the program itself (without any user input).

How to make the script run for user inputs as well ?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547683/python-3-eof-when-reading-a-line-sublime-text-2-is-angry) helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zenity` to get interactive user input ([read more](http://www.howtogeek.com/107537/how-to-make-simple-graphical-shell-scripts-with-zenity-on-linux/))

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

def get_interactive_input(title, text):
    try:
        result =  subprocess.check_output(['zenity','--entry','--title={}'.format(title),'--text={}'.format(text)])
        return result.strip()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        return None


def main():
    print get_interactive_input('asd', 'asdasd asdasd asdasdasd')


main()
```

[image]