# "EOF when reading a line" Python error

Tags: python, atom-editor

```
name = input('Hey what is your name?: ')
print('nice to meet you ',name)
```

Whenever I try to run this I receive the following error :

> "EOF when reading a line".

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: While I consider this question bad form, I saw an answer which provided useful details downvoted. Which form is worse?

Comment: noone knows where the problem lies. that's the issue.

Comment: Veritox, can you describe your execution environment? What OS are you using? Are you running Python from a command line or via a graphical interface?

Comment: ofc, inability to provide an answer can be traced back to the questions form. but deletion of several answers that tried to adress it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15417765/2285236

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail (first time here). Rob, I am using OS X, and on Atom Text Editor.

Comment: Wait- atom? Are you using a run code plugin? In which case the mystery is solved! Atom run code cannot run input!

Comment: Ah, thank you Octo! I am no longer seeing the error, but I can't do the input.

Answer (score -1):

Just a guess: you need to run this *in a terminal* (it does work when run like this). I am thinking that your code does not have any chance to get any input (hence the End Of File warning).