# Read in multiple lines of input at once and store in list (python)

Tags: python, list

When given an input:

```
3
2 1
1 1 0
```

How would I take that input and store it as a list like so:

```
examList = [
      [3],
      [2,1],
      [1,1,0]
]
```

How do you identify the end user input if there any no specific indicators?

Currently have the following code:

```
examList = []
i = input()

while i != '':
    examList.append([int(s) for s in i.split()])
    i = input()
```

But I keep getting EOF errors when reading the last elements into the list.

Comment: Move `print` statement outside of while loop. I've executed this code and didn't face any such error.

Comment: Check if your IDE supports input() function.Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547683/python-3-eof-when-reading-a-line-sublime-text-2-is-angry

Answer (score 1):

```
examList = []
i = input()

while i != "":
    examList.append(list(map(int,i.split())))
    i = input()

print(examList)
```

it can be done in this way.