# Python EOFerror, binarygap

Tags: python, python-3.x, eoferror

```
def dectobin(n):

    return int(bin(n)[2:])
    print(int(bin(n)[2:]))

def solution(r):

    k = dectobin(r)
    print(k)
    m = str(k)
    maxgap=0
    running=0
    for i in (0,len(m)-1):
        if m[i] == 0:
            running = running+1
        elif m[i] == 1:
            if running > maxgap:
                maxgap = running
                running = 0
    print(maxgap)

x = input("give the number")
solution(x)
```

output is given like this

```
 x = input("give the number")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line.
```

Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3: EOF when reading a line (Sublime Text 2 is angry)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547683/python-3-eof-when-reading-a-line-sublime-text-2-is-angry)

Comment: Note: Iterating over `(0,len(m)-1` probably isn't doing what you're expecting it to be doing