# Executing Python commands in Jupyter notebook with prompts

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When the function below is entered into a notebook cell, the output will have an input box to enter the details of the prompt.

```
def a():
    val = raw_input("abc")
    print "Entered value: %s" % val
```

[image]

I'm trying to achieve the same thing by running the script, but it doesn't work. I've copied the same code for the function above into a script `sample.py` as below.

```
# cat sample.py
def a():
    val = raw_input("abc")
    print "Entered value: %s" % val

a()
```

Attempts to achieve the same behavior of getting a notebook prompt while running the script from notebook:

**1. Using the '!' prefix**

This command just keeps running without giving any prompt:

```
[*] !python sample.py
abc
```

**2. Using `%%bash`**

Gives the following error:

```
%%bash
python sample.py
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

What is the reason for this to fail and is there a workaround to get it working as expected?

Comment: Please check:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547683/python-3-eof-when-reading-a-line-sublime-text-2-is-angry I think, this is a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Looks like I need to find a way to bind the notebook stdin to the script output. I'll check this further.

Comment: may be use `%run` magic command

Comment: Thanks @krishna I think this works. Could you post this as an answer so that I could mark that as the correct answer? Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked. I'll post after 3 hour. I'm outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two command you've used are used for shell command and bash script respectively.

To run Python script as a program you can use Magic command [`run`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run).