# Shows a traceback, when there is traceback. What is EOF error

Tags: python

```
$python main.py
Enter a number: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    inp = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: End of File Error

Comment: What are you entering?

Comment: For a UNIX text file to be valid, every line needs to terminated by a newline, including the last one. That's different from Windows, where the last line doesn't require a newline.

Comment: That said, I wonder if you're hiding details (like the left hand side of a pipe, or redirection from a file). An interactive terminal won't provide an EOF unless you tell it to, as by typing ctrl-d

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547683/python-3-eof-when-reading-a-line-sublime-text-2-is-angry could you go through this?