# Filter and sort inputed list of integers for non negative numbers python

Tags: python, sorting, filter

I am trying to take a list that a user inputs, filter and sort in ascending order but only for the non-negative numbers.  I thought I understood how to do this but it will not work with my logic.

```
my_list = []
n = int(input())
for i in range(0, n):
    element = int(input())
    if element > 0:
        my_list.append(element)
my_list.sort()
print(my_list)
```

Here is the error I receive:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10 -7 4 39 -6 12 2' It doesn't like line 2

Comment: I find it very unhelpful that someone gives me a negative for feedback.  I am new to this site and I am trying very hard to understand python.  I was told this was a great site to find helpful tips.  I thought I had provided enough information and I provided my code.  So the negative is not helpful.

Comment: show me input example and the expected output

Comment: 10 -7 4 39 -6 12 2 example input and expected output is only the positive numbers sorting ascending.  So 2 4 10 12 39

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to put the lenght of the array into n and then use the i do define the element:

```
my_list = []
n = len(input().split())
for i in range(0, n):
    element = int(input().split()[i])
    if element > 0:
        my_list.append(element)
my_list.sort()
print(my_list)
```

print:

```
[2, 4, 10, 12, 39]
```

EDIT: The upper version was tested and works with Py 3.8.2

This is working also on https://ideone.com/rDw1w6#stdin using Py 3.7.3

```
my_list = []
my_string_array = input().split()
n = len(my_string_array)
for i in range(0, n):
    element = int(my_string_array[i])
    if element > 0:
        my_list.append(element)
my_list.sort()
print(my_list)
```

Comment: if the return value of input() is a string you need to split it before give it to len

Comment: thank you for the help but this still gives me an error.  specifically the element = int(input().split()[I]).            EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: if your are using sublime text: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547683/python-3-eof-when-reading-a-line-sublime-text-2-is-angry

Comment: Add a version that is working on  https://ideone.com/rDw1w6#stdin what is using Py 3.7.3. My first version was tested on Py 3.8.2

Comment: that was helpful.  Thank you!

Comment: @KrisBlosser, would you be so kind and accept my answer if it as it was helpful for you.  thx.

Comment: I would be happy to but I am not sure I know how

Comment: @KrisBlosser, right beneath the up and down pointing arrows, at the left side of the answer, should be a gray check, which turns green after pressing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
user_input = input()

my_list = [int(i) for i in user_input.split() if (int(i)>=0)] 

my_list.sort()

[print(i, end=' ') for i in my_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# this solution works
user_input = input()
my_list = [int(i) for i in user_input.split() if (int(i)>=0)] 
my_list.sort()
[print(i, end=' ') for i in my_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

[`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns the entire string at once, not the individual elements, so you need to split your input into the individual numbers using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20split#str.split), then convert them to integers (this can be done conveniently using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)) before selecting only the non-negative numbers to put into `my_list` (this can be written as a list comprehension). You can then sort the list with [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list%20sort#list.sort):

```
elements = map(int, input().split())
my_list = [e for e in elements if e >= 0]
my_list.sort()
print(my_list)
```

For input of `10 -7 4 39 -6 12 2`, this produces

```
[2, 4, 10, 12, 39]
```

[Demo on ideone](https://ideone.com/ewNt3T)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie, but there is probably a better way to write this.

```
interger = input().split()

new_interger = []
sorted_list = []

for x in interger:
    new_interger.append(int(x))
    for x in new_interger:
        if x >= 0:
            new_interger.pop()
            sorted_list.append(x)
sorted_list.sort()

for x in sorted_list:
    print(x, end=' ')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I broke it up a little to display the steps required to output the elements of the list rather than the actual list:

```
data = input()

#turn input to a list based on spaces
dat_list = data.split()
#turn elements in list to integers
dat_list = [int(x) for x in dat_list]
#fix list to only include positive integers
dat_list = [i for i in dat_list if pn >= 0]

#sort list
dat_list.sort()

#print each integer in list with a space after 
for i in dat_list:
    print(i, end=' ')
```

Tried to be as explicative as possible for people having a hard time understanding, meaning this is not the shortest or most effective way of doing this, but newbie friendly

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did mine and it works.

```
numbers = input().split()
negative_numbers = []

for num in numbers:
    if int(num) < 0:
        negative_numbers.append(int(num))

negative_numbers.sort(reverse=True)
for num in negative_numbers:
    print(num, end=' ')
```

Comment: I don't why it did that after I posted so u just need to indent