# Python 3: EOF when reading a line (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, eof

I use visual studio code to program in Python, and whenever I try to take user input, Visual Studio Code throws me an "EOF when reading a line" at that specific line. However, this code works perfectly in command line and Python IDLE.

Side note: [Python 3: EOF when reading a line (Sublime Text 2 is angry)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547683/python-3-eof-when-reading-a-line-sublime-text-2-is-angry) is possibly a related question, as the error I am facing seems quite similar, only I am receiving this error in VSC and not Sublime text 2.

I think this might be because VSC has no valid way to take user input, any clarification or suggestion on alternate platforms are welcome.

**Details:**

Coding language: Python 3.8

Text Editor: Visual Studio Code

Code causing the problem:

```
number = int(input('Enter a number:    '))
print (number**2)
```

Error recieved:

```
Exception has occurred: EOFError
EOF when reading a line
  File "<location>", line 1, in <module>
    number = int(input('Enter a number:    '))
```

Comment: `int(input('Enter a number:    '))` Are those plain single-quote characters?  Or are they fancy/angled quotes?

Comment: @JohnGordon They are plain single quote characters, of type ''.

Comment: Looks to me like your input has been redirected and is not coming from a console.

Comment: @MarkRansom Could you elaborate on what you mean? All other code that does not require input works fine in VSC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reproduced the problem you described:

[image]

**Reason:** When we use `"console": "internalConsole",` the result will be output to "`DEBUG CONSOLE`", and this terminal of VSCode is currently only used for display output. When the code needs to be input but input is not received, it will throw "`EOF`" "(End of file), "There is an unexpected error at the end of the file".

**Solution:** please change the output mode of the debugging code. (in `settings.json` file)

1. For the code that needs to be entered, we can use `"console": "integratedTerminal",`

   [image]
2. or use `"console": "externalTerminal",`

   [image]

Reference: [console](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_console) in VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Microsoft Visual Studio Code (and the debug window for code that does not require input), I right-clicked on the code and from the submenu selected the *Run Python File in Terminal* option. Rather than executing in the *Debug* tab, it executed in the *Terminal* tab. I was able to enter an input there and test the input value.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This problem also happened to me. I ran the program with the terminal. At the top right corner, there should be a dedicated button that does so.

Comment: Hello, this is no answer. You should delete this ...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30836269)