# Python EOFError student

Tags: python

Just started an intro to scripting class using Python. My first lab is giving me problems with the EOFError: EOF when reading a line. This is everything I had entered as my input.

```
    first_name = input('Kevin')
    generic_location = input('Target')
    whole_number = input('8')
    plural_noun = input('socks')
    print(first_name, 'went to', generic_location, 'to buy', whole_number, 'different types of', 
    plural_noun)
```

Not sure how to fix it??

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour]. Once you fix the indenting, it runs just fine, but it looks like you put the data where the input prompts should go. What's your desired output? Please [edit] to clarify. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: On second thought, it looks like you're not even supposed to use `input()` here. Try `first_name = 'Kevin'`, etc. (I'm guessing you're running this in some script runner which doesn't actually provide any input on stdin.)

Comment: Related: [Python 3: EOF when reading a line (Sublime Text 2 is angry)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12547683/4518341)

Comment: Awesome that fixed it!

Comment: OK, great! I posted an answer, which is mostly a formality at this point

Answer (score 0):

Once you fix the indenting, it runs just fine, but it looks like you're not supposed to use `input()` here. (I'm guessing you're running this in some script runner which doesn't actually provide any input on stdin.)

```
first_name = 'Kevin'
generic_location = 'Target'
whole_number = '8'
plural_noun = 'socks'
print(first_name, 'went to', generic_location, 'to buy', whole_number, 'different types of',
      plural_noun)
```

Output:

```
Kevin went to Target to buy 8 different types of socks
```

(Indenting the last line is not necessary, but it's good style.)