# How to run python on Sublime Text 2?

Tags: python, sublimetext2, user-input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python 3.1 and Sublime Text 2 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142290/python-3-1-and-sublime-text-2-error)
>   [Sublime Text 2 console input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input)

I just got Sublime Text on my Mac and I'm trying to run simple code with Python, but I don't know how to do it.

> print "hello"

This would run when I press Cmd+B (Build), to output hello

> s = input('How are you?')

But when I try to run this, I would always get an error.

Help please???

Answer (score 3):

I think you intended to do:
    s = raw_input('How are you?')

Comment: input works just fine. See http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input