# EOF when reading a line [Python 3.5]

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimetext

This is the code I'm trying to run in Sublime Text 3 for Windows 64-bit:

```
import time

print ("First to 21 is the winner,")
i=0
while i<21:
    print("you may say",i+1,"or",i+2)
    j=int(input("You say "))
    if j<i+1 or j>i+2:
        print ("You cheated,",)
    else:
        print ("I must say",j+1,"or",j+2,"hmmm...")
        time.sleep(2)
        i=i+3          
        print ("I say",i,)
print ("and I am the winner!")
print ("Had you won, the prize was a golden ruby laser!!")
```

This is the error message I get:

```
You say Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arvid\Documents\Grupdat\Lab3\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    j=int(input("You say "))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Is there an explanation to this problem and how can I avoid it?

Comment: "Run in Sublime Text"...? How exactly are you running that?

Comment: When does this code crash? When running or when trying to run the program. Works fine here when running it in Python 2.7 shell

Comment: @bærten When trying to run the program. It works in IDLE for me but not when I try to run it through Sublime.

Comment: Install sublimeREPL and then choose Tools->sublimerepl->python.
See the two following posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142290/python-3-1-and-sublime-text-2-error and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690657/running-code-in-sublime-text-2-mac-os-x

Comment: @bærten I have sublimeREPL but how do I run the program through the Python tab in Sublime?